# Laravel: Best way to compare two collections: whereIn?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with categories, one table with products and another table products_user which tracks the products a user owns.

When displaying products on a page it should change a button from Buy to Bought if a user owns the product.

I get the products to display through $categories->products. What is the most efficient way to find out which of these products a user already owns?

I don't want to load the entire collection of the user owned products into the memory since these could be several thousands. I also don't want to create a Mysql query for each check.

There is an option for a wherein clause. But even then I am that there is a smarter way to create this clause without looping through every product to build an array.

Can someone help me to come up with a good logic? thank you

Comment: In general, in terms of SQL, you can left join the user's products to the query of products in the category you have selected. User product columns will be null for products in the category that the user doesn't own. You won't load the entire collection of user products that way; only the ones in the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) to append more information to your products. In this case, the user_id is either `NULL` or `user_id`, meaning the user is bought the product or not.

```
$categories = Category::with(['products' => function ($q) {
    $q->select(['products.*', 'user_id'])
        ->leftJoin('products_user', 'user_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->where(function ($q) {
            $q->whereNull('user_id')->orWhere('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        });
}])->get();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $products = $category->products;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if (empty($product->user_id)) {
            // user not yet bought the product
        }
        else {
            // user already bought the product
        }
     }
}
```